# Replace something before then replace something else after a searched point in a file

Tags: xml, shell, replace, sed, sh

i'm trying to do a shell script that dynamically do a find and replace in an **XML file**.

with sed i find an unique string in the file, now the problem is i have to replace another string that is some lines before, and then replace another one that is some lines after this unique string.

***example***

```
<Field name="Bytes" type="com.sunopsis.sql.DbInt"><![CDATA[250]]></Field>
<Field name="CheckFlow" type="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[0]]></Field>
<Field name="CheckStat" type="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[0]]></Field>
[. . .] Other Lines like this
The next line is my UNIQUE string
<Field name="ColName" type="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[COMPANY_NAME_BG]]></Field>
[. . .] Other Lines like this
<Field name="Longc" type="com.sunopsis.sql.DbInt"><![CDATA[250]]></Field>
[. . .] Other Lines like this
```

***Result should be***

```
<Field name="Bytes" type="com.sunopsis.sql.DbInt"><![CDATA[REPLACEMENT]]></Field>
<Field name="CheckFlow" type="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[0]]></Field>
<Field name="CheckStat" type="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[0]]></Field>
[. . .] Other Lines like this
The next line is my UNIQUE string
<Field name="ColName" type="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[COMPANY_NAME_BG]]></Field>
[. . .] Other Lines like this
<Field name="Longc" type="com.sunopsis.sql.DbInt"><![CDATA[REPLACMENT]]></Field>
[. . .] Other Lines like this
```

I have to find and edit **only the first occurrence (before/after)** for each UNIQUE string i find

Comment: Stock advice: do not manipulate XML data with line-oriented tools like `sed`. Use something like `xsltproc` and `xmlstarlet`.

Comment: how could i solve my problem using this?

Comment: That depends on what the line with your "UNIQUE" string is supposed to be.

Comment: the one you see in the example it's <Field name="ColName" one

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly, then this is what you would do with `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
  -u '//Field[@name="Bytes"]' -x  'following-sibling::Field[@name="ColName"][1]/text()' \
  -u '//Field[@name="Longc"]' -x  'preceding-sibling::Field[@name="ColName"][1]/text()' \
  input.xml
```

This works as follows: `-u XPATH` means "update" the element or attribute specified by the following xpath expression, and `-x XPATH` means update it with the element or attribute specified by the following xpath expression (use `-v` for fixed values). We select the *Field* elements with a name attribute of either *Bytes* or *Longc*. Now, since the "Bytes Field" precedes the "ColName Field", we select the **next following** "ColName Field", and since the "Longc Field" follows the "ColName Field", we select the **last previous** "ColName Field" (the indexing is slightly counter-intuitive). the `text()` expression selects the content of the element, but this is optional.

Comment: Could you explain me better how it works?

ed\ it's edit mode and that's clear, what about -u -x text() and etc. ?

Comment: mmm i don't think it works for me, because my fixed unique string of reference is "ColName", first i have to find the right ColName and then replace the preceding Bytes and the following Longc.

Comment: Since there are a lot of similar xml structures, and i have to find the correct one by matching the unique ColName Field

Comment: It seems that I do not understand your problem, or you do not understand my explanation. In the OP, you write **for each UNIQUE string**, but now it seems there is only one string you are interested in?

Comment: so are you telling me that i have to write my unique string in place of text()?

Comment: No, that won't work. Maybe you should rephrase your original question.

Comment: I think the example is quite clear, i have to find an unique ColName string, and then make a replace of the relative "Bytes" and "LongC" strings (the first is preceding the second is following "ColName")